# How to use OpenCV to process the example picture

Tags: c++, opencv

I need some suggestion in processing the following image.
Basically, I want to remove the background which is a dark red table and leave the filter (a white background and a gray spot in the middle)

This picture is taken by the camera. I think in a real experiment, the background may not be a single color but the type of filter always be the same.

edit:

1. The desired object could be anywhere in the picture.
2. The background could be anything not just the dark red
3. But the object is always white

I am using OpenCV to process this image, any suggestion about what types of method of OpenCV should be used for this example.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: probably you don't just want to process this single image, right? Will the desired object always be in the center of the image? Will tje background always be red and the object always be white?

Comment: I made some changes about the question. Hopefully, answered your questions.

Comment: can the background be white, too?

Comment: Actually, I want to detect the edge of the gray spot in the white filter. My algorithm works fine if the background is white since there would be much less noise. But it does not work if the background color is not white. For example, the dark red background generate a lot of noise when I try to use the edge detection method.  So I am thinking about removing the background color first.

Comment: 1. try (adaptive?)  thresholding to finf all whitish regions 2. use their contour and remove all outside of the white contours 3. detect the filter